# Javascript date returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, date

I'm new to Java script and am literally tearing my hair out here. I want a simple date calculator, which updates itself when ever a user changes either a date box or a duration from a drop down menu. I've looked at several ways to do it, and have found one that appears to be quite simple as per below.

It works perfectly if I have 'var interval = 4;' as a fixed value (interval is the duration after the user inputted date). However if I change that line to 'var interval = number;' (the duration input from the select menu), it gives me all kinds of crazy dates(dates which are significantly after the interval), and I don't know why

Is anyone able to help? Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setExpDate(){

var formDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
var number = document.getElementById('days').value;

// set number of days to add
var interval = 4;
var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(formDate));
var expDate = startDate;
expDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = expDate;
document.getElementById('daysdays').innerHTML = interval;
};
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" id="startDate" name="startDate" onblur="setExpDate(this.value)">

<select name="days" id="days" onchange="setExpDate(this.value)">
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
<option value="05">5</option>
<option value="06">6</option>
<option value="07">7</option>
```

```
 <div id="total"></div> <br/><div id="daysdays"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of form fields are always strings. You have to force them to be numbers:

```
var number = +document.getElementById('days').value;
```

or

```
var number = parseInt( document.getElementById('days').value, 10 );
```

(Either one will work; it's up to you.)

If you don't perform that conversion, then the addition step here:

```
    expDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);
```

will be carried out as string concatenation.